# How to stop broadcastreceiver from main activity?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo

I start 5 Broadcastreceiver at different time and I can cancel them all, if I cancel them before their start.

I want to be able to cancel a broadcastreceiver during runtime. Is there any way to stop a running broadcastreceiver?

```
alarmmanger.cancel(pendingIntent1); - does not work.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "start 5 Broadcastreceiver"? Do you call `registerReceiver()` for them somewhere? What exactly do you mean by "cancel a broadcastreceiver"? Do you mean you want to unregister it? Or do you mean to want to stop execution of `onReceive()` if it happens to be executing?

Comment: I want to start onReceive(); 5 times. I created 5 PendingIntents and I want to be able to stop the execution of onReceive();

Comment: I dont know how to stop onReceive: For example - if onReceive(); runs for the next 10 Minutes and I want to stop it after 2 Minutes -  how can I do this?

Comment: `onReceive()` doesn't run continuously, nor do `BroadcastReceiver`s themselves really "run" continuously. They are registered, and their `onReceive()` methods will be invoked when they receive a relevant `Intent`. To "stop" them, you would unregister them, but I don't think that's what you're asking. Are you just trying to cancel alarms?

Comment: Does it means that I can run onReceive() more than one time / intent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `onReceive()` will run once per broadcast. It is possible to broadcast the same `Intent` instance multiple times.

Comment: ahh okayy. I get it. Thanks. You helped me a lot  : ))

Comment: I think you need to post your comment as an answer @MikeM.

Comment: @rmanalo I'm still not sure what they're asking, so I wouldn't even know what to put in an answer.

Comment: @MikeM. your second comment gives an insight to how a thing work which is `BroadcastReceiver`. I would have made that comment an answer and maybe add the real answer part below if I think I need to.